socket io flask connection issue
I am new in Socketio,i integrate it with Flask also I have an issue with sending events when it connects but nothing happens, as the fired message is not printed when socket send message
here is my code :

from myproject import app
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run(debug=True)
    socketio.run(app,debug=True)


this controller  code
from flask import render_template,url_for,flash,redirect,request,Blueprint,request,json,jsonify,session,Response
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required
from myproject import db
from myproject import app
from myproject.models import User ,Presentaions,PresntaionImages,PresntaionVideos,Settings,Colors,Hand,PresnterFrameMode,SlidingMode
from myproject.users.dataValidator import *
from myproject.handler import *
import datetime 
from sqlalchemy import func 
from sqlalchemy.sql import text


# Define a Flask Blueprint named 'streaming'
streaming = Blueprint('streaming', __name__)
    
@streaming.route('/streaming/show/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def show(id):
    
    presntaion = Presentaions.query.filter_by(id=id, deleted=1).first()

    pagetitle = "Presenter X | Streaming Details"
    return render_template('streaming_template/show.html', presntaion=presntaion,pagetitle=pagetitle)
  

@socketio.on('message')
def message(data):
    send(data)
    print(f"Message received: {data}") 

this my  js code
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // Connect to websocket
  var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    

    // Retrieve username
    socket.on('connect',()=>{
      socket.send("i am connected");
    //console.log("WebSocket connected");

    });

I tried more and more for searching to solve this issue

There isn't enough detail in the code snippets that you posted. I suggest you start from a working example and modify it to match your needs. For example, use the one in the Flask-SocketIO repository on GitHub.
